# Three players toss coins, what is the probability of one of them gets an outcome different from those of the other two?

Tags: probability

Could anyone help me with this Probability problem from the book First Course in Probability by Sheldon Ross, please?

> Three players simultaneously toss coins. The coin
> tossed by A(B)[C] turns up heads with probability
> $P_{1}(P_{2})[P_{3}]$. If one person gets an outcome different from those of the other two, then he is the odd man out. If there is no odd man out, the players flip
> again and continue to do so until they get an odd
> man out. What is the probability that A will be the
> odd man?

From what I could understand about this problem, there are two disjoint possibilities of A losing the game: (A = head, B = tail, C = tail) and (A = tail, B = head, C = head). Then the result should be:

$P_{1}(1-P_{2})(1-P_{3})+(1-P_{1})(P_{2})(P_{3})$

What am I missing?

Book solution:

$\frac{P_{1}(1-P_{2})(1-P_{3})+(1-P_{1})(P_{2})(P_{3})}{P_{1}+P_{2}+P_{3}-P_{1}P_{2}-P_{2}P_{3}-P_{1}P_{3}}$

Comment: The problem asks for a conditional probability...the probability that $A$ has lost given that someone has lost.  What you wrote is different, it is the probability that $A$ loses in a single round.

Comment: @lulu Now I understand the solution, thank you! But still, why calculating the probability of A losing in a single round is wrong for this problem?

Comment: Because that wasn't what was asked.  If, say, $p_1=p_2=p_3$ then, of course, the answer has to be $\frac 13$ by symmetry.  But that doesn't mean that each player has a $\frac 13$ chance of losing on a specified round.  If, say, all three probabilities were $.999$ then it will be a long time before somebody loses.

Answer (score 1):

The probability that no-one is odd-one-out is

$$D=P_1P_2P_3 +(1-P_1)(1-P_2)(1-P_3)$$

so the overall probability is

$$P_{1}(1-P_{2})(1-P_{3})+(1-P_{1})(P_{2})(P_{3})(1+D+D^2+\dots)$$

$$=\frac{P_1(1-P_2)(1-P_3)+(1-P_1)(P_2)(P_3)}{1-D}$$

But $$1-D$$$$=\left(P_1+(1-P_1)\right)\left(P_2+(1-P_2)\right)\left(P_3+(1-P_3)\right)-D$$

$$=P_1 + P_2 + P_3 - P_1P_2 - P_1P_3 - P_2P_3$$